# Passing value from Spinner/EditText in one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, android-spinner

When I pass values directly from a string to another activity, it works. But if I retrieve the same values from an EditText and a Spinner and I click on a button (which starts the new activity), the app crashes.

With this my app works:

```
    String key;
    String para;
    Button btnViewProducts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        //StrictMode.enableDefaults();

        // Buttons
        btnViewProducts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewProducts);
        key = "kq";
        para = "Taxi_No";

        // View products click event
        btnViewProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching All products Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("keyval", key);
                i.putExtra("paraval",para);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // View products click event
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
    String key;
    String para;
    Spinner spin;
    EditText keyw;
    Button btnViewProducts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        //StrictMode.enableDefaults();

        btnViewProducts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewProducts);
        Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinpara);
        EditText keyw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kser);
        key = keyw.getText().toString();
        para = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

        // View products click event
        btnViewProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching All products Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                i.putExtras(b);
                i.putExtra("keyval", key);
                 i.putExtra("paraval",para);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // View products click event
    }
}
```

This is my [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file) output:

```
04-25 00:58:31.634: W/ResourceType(335): Skipping entry 0x7f040003 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
04-25 00:58:31.644: W/dalvikvm(335): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.MainScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.example.androidhive.MainScreenActivity.onCreate(MainScreenActivity.java:30)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     ... 11 more
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     ... 22 more
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:214)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:361)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:628)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.<init>(AbsSpinner.java:73)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:56)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:52)
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     ... 25 more
```

I have to get those parameters from the text field and spinner selected value. What changes have to be made to the code?

Comment: post the logcat. I see several things that could be giving you trouble

Comment: @codeMagic: i have been trying for several hours.Wil you please point out the faults u detected? i changed the object instance creation code to this:   spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinpara);
                keyw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.kser);   THANKS

Comment: If you post the logcat I sure will. I can only assume without seeing what is causing the exception. I also would like to know what `b` is in `i.putExtras(b);` I assume its a `Bundle` but is it declared anywhere?

Comment: @codeMagic:i already commented the bundle statement. missed it while posting here. posted the logcat jst nw. Thanks

Comment: Look here, `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:214)` it looks like you are trying to access an array that doesn't exist or isn't declared properly

Comment: @codeMagic:sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinpara);
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.para_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);    i have set this array to display spinner options and also declared that array in strings.xml. this is correct i guess.

Comment: Hard to read but it looks about right. Put a breakpoint in there and check what is returned for your `Array`.

Comment: @codeProject:It worked. i had set the wrong array to the spinner. I have been developing this since the past month. Thanks a ton. Android app development is new to me and i am not yet used to debugging it from the logcat. THANKS again.

Comment: I have added a note to my answer regarding logcat in case it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the logcat, this line here tells us about the problem

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-25 00:58:31.695: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at
    android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:214)
```

Tells us that the `Array` being used for your `Spinner` is `null`. Check that you are using the correct name for your `Array` in `Spinner`

Also note that it seems  that it is generally better to use `Activity Context` instead of `Application Context` unless that is really what you need. your `Intent` could be

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this, AllProductsActivity.class);
```

This obviously isn't your problem here but its something to keep in mind

**Logcat**

Logcat can be tricky at first but look for the line that says `Caused by:NullpointerException, IllegalArgument, etc...` then the first line of code after that which references your project is normally a good place to start

Comment: Thanks i will surely keep that in mind. but what difference does it make? i have googled it right now.

Comment: Certain things need one or the other. There are good answers on SO that explain it better than I could. I have rarely ever needed to use Application `context`. Search on here for "Application context or Activity Context" and you will find good explanations